# Generate shibboleth IdP metadata

Tags: saml-2.0, shibboleth

I was thrown on a project where I need to implement web sso. I'm new to SAML. I've set up shibboleth idp. How do I generate IdP metadata in order to give it to service providers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's located in

```
{shibboleth installation folder}/metadata/idp-metadata.xml
```

Answer (score 5):

The default location for shibboleth-idp metadata is in either of the following locations :

```
Shibboleth-idp-installation/metadata/idp-metadata.xml
```

**or**

```
idp-url/shibboleth
```